# Field defines a relation with model 'Entity', which is either not installed, or is abstract

Tags: python, django, entity-framework

I am using django model inheritance to create an Entity model, so that I can reference two foreign keys in the Conversation model, as entity_1 and entity_2 can be a Person or Business. However I keep getting the following error message:

```
api.Conversation.entity_1: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Entity', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
api.Conversation.entity_2: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Entity', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

This is my code so far:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)

    class Meta:
         abstract = True

 class Person(Entity):
    """
    Person model
    """

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_avatar_path, blank=True, null=True, default=None, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Business(Entity):
    """
    Business model
`   """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, default=None)


class Conversation(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    entity_1 = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    entity_2 = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
```

Comment: you can not reference to an abstract class. It does not create a database table.

Comment: @trantu what should I do then? I would like to entity_1 and entity_2 to both reference Person and Business, so I can access each from the Conversation model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can not reference to an abstract class. It does not create a database table.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

You can use GenericForeignKey
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

an example:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
class Conversation(models.Model):
    entity_one = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='entity_one')
    entity_two = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='entity_two')
    entity1_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    entity2_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    entity_1_object = GenericForeignKey('entity_one', 'entity1_id')
    entity_2_object = GenericForeignKey('entity_two', 'entity2_id')
```

Comment: Thanks. I have read through the article and I am still a bit unclear as to how this would fit into the context of my code? Can you please provide an easy to follow example that fits in with what I am doing?

Comment: This is what I have done so far: http://pastebin.com/2KbXHkQh, I keep getting the error message `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GenericForeignKey'`

Comment: you have to call `from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey`. I posted an example. Please look at that.

Comment: @trantu: You also need to add `entity_1_id` and `entity_2_id` and use those in `GenericForeignKey`. You can not use `object_id` for both (and which is not even declared).

Comment: It still won't work you need to define `entity_1_id` and `entity_2_id` as PositiveIntegerField.