# How to show child table in Django REST Framework API view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using **Django** as *Backend*, PostgresSQl as DB and HTML, CSS and Javascript as Frontend. I want to show Children Table in `DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK`, as I'm using **Multi Table Inheritance**.
[image]

As we can see in above image, that only Product list is been displayed but not the children table. I want to show all the data which is selected by customer. I'm showing Cart Product in DRF

**views.py**

```
class AddToCartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "status.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        product_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        product_obj = Product.objects.get(id = product_id)
        cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id", None)
        if cart_id:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id = cart_id)
            this_product_in_cart = cart_obj.cartproduct_set.filter(product = product_obj)
        
            if this_product_in_cart.exists():
                cartproduct = this_product_in_cart.last()
                cartproduct.quantity += 1
                cartproduct.subtotal += product_obj.price
                cartproduct.save()
                cart_obj.total += product_obj.price
                cart_obj.save()
            else:
                cartproduct = CartProduct.objects.create(
                    cart = cart_obj, product = product_obj, rate = product_obj.price, quantity = 1, subtotal = product_obj.price)
                cart_obj.total += product_obj.price
                cart_obj.save() 
        else:
            cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(total=0)
            self.request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
            cartproduct = CartProduct.objects.create(
                cart = cart_obj, product = product_obj, rate = product_obj.price, quantity = 1, subtotal = product_obj.price)
            cart_obj.total += product_obj.price
            cart_obj.save()

        return context
```

**API View (views.py)**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def showproduct(request):
    result = CartProduct.objects.all()
    serialize = productserializers(result, many = True)
    return Response(serialize.data)
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1330)
    image_src = models.URLField(max_length=1330,null=True, blank=True)
    link_href = models.URLField(max_length=1330,null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length = 1330, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)


class Refrigerator(Product):
    series = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Cart(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cart: " + str(self.id)


class CartProduct(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    subtotal = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cart: " + str(self.cart.id) + " CartProduct: " + str(self.id)
```

## I want to show refrigerator details aslo in DRF which is been selected by customer.

**serializer.py**

```
class productserializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartProduct
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 2
```

Comment: why do you create the Refrigerator model?

Comment: Actually, I want to work on my website like this. [link](https://buildmypc.net/list/). where i want to all the list to be displayed on one page. with there specification. so that's why i Did this

Comment: Is it right way to do @KiranChauhan?

Comment: only create one product table and add 1 field in a table like "type" so you can add multiple types of product "fan", "refrigerator"..etc

I already show you in a previous answer how to link product table with category table

Comment: ok I will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, in your `Product(models.Model)`

```
 class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

you can refer here for explanation : [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)
(I should have comment this but don't have enough reputations for that :/)

Comment: Hello Rahul I'm getting error. **`Field defines a relation with model 'Product', which is either not installed, or is abstract`**

Comment: @santoshChauhan now you have to add Product as a Foreign Key in your refrigerator model to make it work, check this link it might help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086509/field-defines-a-relation-with-model-entity-which-is-either-not-installed-or)

Comment: Hello Rahul , as you said I have to use `abstract = True` , it will not help me because when you see my `CartProduct` Model where I'm using `Product` Model as a base class and my problem is one and only one thing is that, I cant access the child table with parent table which is selected by user. I want to show in DRF, is which child model is selected and my DRF showing Only Parent table.

Comment: @santoshChauhan, i thought it would work is it solved now?

Comment: NO brother it doesnot solve for me? Now I makee different apps for different model